# How to create MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have table `users` with two fields `id` (numeric) and `email` (with full email adress)  how to add trigger which can prevent adding new `email` records with specific domains eg: `*@somedomain.com`?

Comment: By using the `create trigger` command in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).

Comment: AFAIK it is hard to use a trigger to block an insert or update.  Could you peform this check in your app layer?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is no too hard to prevent an insert or update in a trigger by raising an error, but you definitely have a point that this should be done in the application, rather than in a trigger.

Comment: you can create trigger which listen to insert statement and base on its value it will trigger delete statment

Answer (score 1):

The trigger would look like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER USER_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON USER
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.email like '%@somedomain.com' THEN
    SIGNAL sqlstate '99999'
        SET message_text = 'Invalid domain';
  END IF;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER example_before_insert_reject_domains
     BEFORE INSERT ON example_tbl FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.email LIKE '%@somedomain.com'
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: invalid domain for email';
          END IF;
     END;
$$
```